# Careers Sidebar does not display any jobs

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs, sidebar

Currently the Careers sidebar on Stackoverflow is showing up empty.  In the console, I see the following:

```
GET http://careers.stackoverflow.com/gethired/js 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The details:

- Browser: Chrome 28.0.1500.71
- OS: Mac OS X 10.8.4

Comment: this was likely a brief issue on that day only.